# Profiling computations in Turbo Pascal and Turbo C

Tags: profiling, turbo-c, turbo-pascal

I recently been doing some tasks for university, which include using Turbo Profiler (the software is implicitly declared in the task, sadly) for profiling C and Pascal implementations of Simpsons numerical integration. I came across very strange case, where Pascal is suspiciously much faster than C.

Pascal:

```
i: integer, lower: real, delta_x: real;
....
(0.0000 seconds) (30 times)         x:=lower+delta_x*(2.0*i-1.0);
```

C:

```
long i, double lower, double delta_x;
....
(0.0549 seconds) (30 times)         double x = lower + delta_x * (2.0 * i - 1.0);
```

So, what could it be, the difference between `real` and `double` (and `integer` and `long`) or just Pascal's compiler better at processing math operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*Don't believe those numbers.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771) If you want to measure time, put a loop of 10^6 or 10^9 iterations around the top subroutine, and count seconds. If you want to see what fraction of time goes into that statement, use stack-sampling.

Answer (score 2):

The *REAL* of Pascal of Pascal is like *FLOAT* in C, an alias for the fastest floating point type on the given system.

So both fragments are not equivalent, in Pascal the most optimal type is used, and in C you hardcode double, the highest precision type (if we forget 80-bit floats)

In TP real default means an *48-bit* soft floating point, but in many later programs {$N+} is added, which maps it onto x87 double.

I don't know Turbo C that well, but it could be that your (64-bit) double type is emulated (depending on settings), which would explain the performance degradation since obviously the emulation of a floating point value with more significant digits is slower. Or worse, you are benchmarking hardware FPU vs software somewhere.